# Angular Material matListItemIcon turns the icons gray after upgrade to v15

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

After upgrading Angular Material to v15, the icons in `mat-list` using `matListItemIcon` are colored gray. In the previous versions, I was able to use `[ngClass]="blue"` with a css class `.blue { color: blue }` and it would style the icon appropriately. Is there a different way to style these icons?

I've tried using `matListItemAvatar` and that works just fine with `ngClass`, but it cuts off the icon because it's shaped in a circle.

Comment: The matListItemIcon icons change to primary theme color when the mat-list-option list item is selected. It looks like you're using mat-list instead of mat-selection-list, so I am not sure if that helps, but my theory is that this is why it changed.

Comment: You were right, i was using mat-list instead of mat-selected-list, but in this case, i'm just displaying a simple list with no option to select anything. I was just curious to see if that would have made a change by going to mat-select-list instead of mat-list and it didn't resolve the issue. So far, the only thing to resolve it is to use matListItemAvatar instead of matListItemIcon. Very bizzare. Thank you for your insight though

Comment: i'm wondering if it has anything to do with https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26723

Comment: Funny, that's actually my issue I created for this problem 

Comment: Not only are the icons gray but so is the list text. I want all the text in a multiline list item to be black like the title (as it used to be pre-15)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `'blue'` class on your `mat-icon` tag the following should work for you now:

```
 .mdc-list-item--with-leading-icon .mdc-list-item__start.blue { 
     color: blue; 
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uradqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Flist-overview-example.ts

Comment: I noticed that as well, but it seems like a workaround. I'm wondering if I missed something with the update to Angular 15 or if this is a regression and I should submit a bug report.

I'm also trying to stay away from using !important in my css which I think might work although I didn't try it